# Convert CMYK to RGB

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The original file I received from the client color mode is CMYK, and I need to create RGB files from it, How can I do that in the most proper way, without facing any color problems or having to create the artwork from scratch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File > Document Color Mode > RGB`

Then, if you need to adjust colors, you'll have to adjust them.

There's no simple easy method of switching color modes and maintaining exact colors in every instance. However, converting from CMYK to RGB should present little, if any, problems. It's when you covert from RGB to CMYK most color shifts occur. The RGB gamut is much larger than the CMYK gamut and the RGB gamut encompasses all colors possible in CMYK.

Comment: "Then, if you need to adjust colors, you'll have to adjust them"

adjusting the colors here means to change to RGB HEX code to whatever color I want?

Comment: Well, change the HEX to more closely match the original color if the color has shifted. Chances are going CMYK -> RGB there's not going to much noticeable difference.